# Xcode 4 - Analyze issues won't show in editor

Tags: xcode4, analyzer

Running Analyze in Xcode 4.0.2 shows issues in the Issue Navigator. Clicking on an issue makes the appropriate file appear in the Editor pane, but nowhere does it show where in the code the issue occurs as I am used to from Xcode 3.x. Does anyone know how I can turn on this feature?

Comment: On further exploration, the problem occurs only on some projects.  Other projects show the issues inline in the editor just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips:

First, if you're looking for the view where Xcode annotates the project with arrows, bear in mind that you may need to expand the top-level analyser result in Xcode's Issue navigator and click the second-level issue in order to see those - see screenshots.

**Screenshot 1: top-level issue selected - no arrows**

[image]

**Screenshot 2: second-level issue selected - arrows!**

[image]

Second tip: if that stuff isn't working, try cleaning the project's build products folder. Hold down the Option (alt) key and choose **Clean Build Folder...** from the Product menu. (You need to hold down the Option key, otherwise you won't see that menu option.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately my editor is not showing the arrows (as in your pic 2) or even highlighting the line with the issue (as in pic 1), whether I have the result expanded or not. Doing Clean Build Folder is an interesting suggestion, but when I hold Option down, the Clean Build Folder menu item is grayed out. Any idea why that would be? Perhaps it is related to my problem.

Comment: Hmm... weird. Where is your build folder? (Do a build targeted at a device rather than a simulator then ctrl-click the .app under Products and choose Show in Finder.)

Comment: And yes, that could be related - when I look at the analyser output log in Xcode it's both reading from and writing to the build directory. If Xcode can't find your build directory or doesn't have permission to access it I'm assuming that would prevent the analyser from doing its stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before sometimes. I believe it's a bug in Xcode. Restart Xcode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

One note.  I'm seeing this for files that are referenced *outside* the current project.  I currently have a library in which the files with missing annotations live and simply added them to my current project without copying them.  Haven't done the project dependency setup yet, so if you're referring to files outside your project that could be why.  (I opened the library project, did an analyze and the annotations showed up.)

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo, I've nailed it! At least for me. I've been struggling with this problem for about 2 hours now, trying out all the things suggested here and more (Xcode 4.0.2, Snow Leopard). Bizarre thing was I had one file where the warning *were* correctly showing in the editor. Then I noticed the difference to all other files; in the File Inspector pane the location was specified as "Relative to Project" (*warnings show correctly in the editor*), all the other project files were "Relative to Group" (*warnings not showing in the editor*).

I took one of the problem files, switched it's location to "Relative to Project", reanalyzed and bingo! I've see it's warnings in the editor.

I guess this ties in a bit with David Goodine's answer refering to files outside the project.